# Spring Boot Swagger File Upload not working, file is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, springfox

I am documenting an REST API using swagger but file upload isn't working through the swagger interface. File is coming as null.

```
@PostMapping(value = "upload")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Upload a Document",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "tenantId", required = true, paramType = "header"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "docImageOne", required = true, dataType = "file", paramType = "body"),
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "docImageTwo", dataType = "file", paramType = "body"),
    })
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = UploadResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    public ResponseEntity<?> identify(final @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                                      final @RequestBody MultipartFile docImageOne,
                                      final @RequestBody Optional<MultipartFile> docImageTwo)
    {}
```

Not sure what I am missing, any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: As I remember it need the swagger js with a particular version.

Comment: I am using io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.7.0

Comment: paramType should be form